# jQuery executes before Google map loads: "map is undefined"

Tags: google-maps, jquery

Aside from jQuery and Google Maps, I have two scripts included in the head of my page:

```
<script src="js/map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

map.js contains the code to initialize my map and also have the following function to place a marker on it:

```
function placeMarker(marker){
    clearLocations();

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(marker.lat),
        parseFloat(marker.lng)
    );

    var marker = createMarker(latlng);

    map.setZoom(14);
    var latLng = marker.getPosition();
    map.setCenter(latLng);          

}
```

When I call `placeMarker` inside `$(document).ready()` in site.js, I get the error, 'map is undefined'. However when I call another function in site.js that executes when a button is clicked, `placeMarker` runs in its callback without a problem:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/json.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'search_string='+inpMapSearch+'&country='+Country,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        placeMarker(data);
    }
});
```

Does this mean that the `placeMarker` function call inside `$(document).ready()` is trying to execute before the map is initialized? How can I run `placeMarker` after the map is initialized?

**=== EDIT ===**

As per request here is the code that initializes the map:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', load);

function load() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.735693,-70.162651),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
    });
}
```

Comment: In map.js outside of its $(document).ready(). It's the only line of code in that file that's not inside a function.

Comment: Interesting question. We're in need of a testcase to answer it, though.

Comment: Show the code that initializes `map`

Comment: That's because the document.ready fires BEFORE the window load event. Hence you're trying to use the map before it's been instantiated.

Comment: Hence a different event should be passed to addDomListener? If so, which one? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: "It's the only line of code in that file that's not inside a function." Looks like you lied?!

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's the addDomListener method call that isn't in a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the window load event fires **after** the `document.ready`. Hence your map is initialized after the document.ready. You could instead wrap your other code in the [$(window).load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

```
$(window).load(function(){
    your code here 
});
```